# Display ajax response into input field

Tags: jquery, ajax

is there any way to display ajax response into input field?
thanks

Comment: Yep, just put the response text into the value attribute of the input field. Could you show some code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

Using jQuery this looks like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/test.php',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#your-input').val(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: To add to simon's answer a little... For an `input` the `.val()` attribute works whereas `.html()` does not.

Answer (score 0):

check this : [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

```
$("id").val(
 $.ajax({
      url: "script.php",
      global: false,
      type: "POST",
      data: ({id : this.getAttribute('id')}),
      dataType: "html",
      async:false,
      success: function(msg){
         alert(msg);
      }
   }
).responseText);
```