# how to insert/pass an result value city into input field value=“city”

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This script works well, the town that it generates function must register in  but he generates so  city

how to insert/pass value `#city` into input field

> value="cityname"

```
<input id="city" name="input" value="cityname" />

<script>
$(document).ready( function () {    
    var lat = 37.42;
    var long = -122.08;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng="+lat+","+long+"&sensor=false",
        data: {},
        success: function(data) {
            $('#city').html(data);
            $.each( data['results'],function(i, val) {
                $.each( val['address_components'],function(i, val) {
                    if (val['types'] == "locality,political") {
                        if (val['long_name']!="") {
                            $('#city').html(val['long_name']);
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#city').html("unknown");
                        }
                        console.log(i+", " + val['long_name']);
                        console.log(i+", " + val['types']);
                    }
                });
            });
            console.log('Success');
        },
        error: function () { console.log('error'); } 
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: Replace all `$('#city').val(....);` with `$('#city').val(....);`

Comment: The input has the val attribute ,it contain the value of this last , in Jquery use `$(inputselector).val(value)` to set values and to `$(inputselector).val()` get values .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display ajax response into input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623743/display-ajax-response-into-input-field)

Comment: This script works well, the town that it generates function must register in <input value = "city"> but he generates so <input value = ""> city </ input>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directly write :

```
$('#city').val(val['long_name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

To assign a value to an input field use `.val()`:

```
$('input#city').val(newValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Substitute

```
$("#city").val(/* value to set */)
```

for each occurrence of

```
$("#city").html(/* value to set */)
```

Comment: This script works well, the town that it generates function must register in <input id="city" value = "city"> but he generates so <input id="city" value = ""> city </ input>

Comment: Was `$("#city").html(/* value to set */)` replaced with `$("#city").val(/* value to set */)` at `js` ?

Comment: Does `$('#city').val(val['long_name'])` return expected results ?