# Input Box is not appearing?

Tags: php, html, dom

I coded [adding comments function to RSS articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50181624/how-can-variable-and-that-value-move-freely-in-the-cycle-of-php-html-js-php)

In the twists and turns, it is in php coding to show and enter comments. However, the input box does not appear. 
[image]

**Here is the php code:**

```
$url = "./comments/" . $q.".txt";
//댓글 파일에서 컨텐츠 문자열 가져오기
$txtcomment = file_get_contents($url,true);    
//댓글 나열
echo "<ol>";

if ($q !== "" ) {            
                 $comm = $txtcomment;
                 $arr = [];
                 $arr = explode("--",$comm);
             for ($i=4;$i<count($arr);$i++) {
            echo "<li>".$arr[$i]."</li>";            
       } 
    } else {
    echo "해당기사가 없습니다.";
  }

echo "</ol>";

//중첩검색&결과내 검색 폼 만들기
echo "<br><form class=\"category B\" >
Comment: <input type=\"text\" name=\"comment1\" id=\"comment1\" onkeyup=\"inputComment()\" > 
</form>";
```

Why?
Thank for your concern.

Comment: use browser developer tools to see if its simply hidden as you not got standard ordered lists so it could be the CSS. Also you can use single quotes in PHP :/

Comment: What's the source code of the page (the HTML _output_ of the script) looking like?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yeah, Thank you for single quotation comment. after now, I'll use that. But, input box is not still. CSS doesn't have hidden function about input tag.

Comment: @stickybi  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50181624/how-can-variable-and-that-value-move-freely-in-the-cycle-of-php-html-js-php is the previous coding I done.  'Cause Input box is not, I cannot code js inputComment().

Comment: @stickybit Sorry, I edited my post. Url is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Since I use RSS, I presume that php does not properly pass the attributes of the input tag in between. I started to change the old coding.

In other words, I decided that the Show Comments and the input comments were different from the beginning.

[getrss.php code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50181624/how-can-variable-and-that-value-move-freely-in-the-cycle-of-php-html-js-php) as below at first.

```
echo " <option  id=".$i." onclick=\"showComment".$i."(this.value)\" value=".$item_link4."> Show Comments </option>";
```

but, I added the input code as like

```
  echo " <option  id=".$i." onclick=\"showComment".$i."(this.value)\" value=".$item_link4."> Show Comments </option>";
  echo "댓글: <input type='text' name='inputComment' size='200' id='input".$i."' onclick='inputComment".$i."(this.value)' >
              <input type='text' name='txtfile' id='txt".$i."' value=".$item_link4." hidden>
              <div id='comment".$i."'><b>information will be listed here.</b></div>";
```

And, I make input box as a below picture.
[image]

In the end, I am trying to solve the problem in a roundabout way.
But, I still wonder why ajax's ajax is not working!!

After I input my comment, at once I see that. 
[image]

further coding makes a below picture.
[image]
Thanks a lot for your sharing.

[image]

Comment: may be their is an error in ajax code, use developer console in browser to see error.

Comment: @AmmarAli Yeah, something may be wrong. But, now my level of knowledge is below that. Someday i will get it.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623743/display-ajax-response-into-input-field] check this link.

Comment: @AmmarAli Good source! But, I use only javascript not jQuery. Lately, js and Jquery are simultaneously doing in a html page? no Conflicting?